# Syntax in spss for calculating the proportion

Tags: syntax, spss

I need syntax, with which i can make a cross-table in SPSS,where in cells , there would be a fraction of the sum by column.

For example:

```
var 1-column    var 2 string
1                       0
0                       0
1                       1
0                       1
1                       1
0                       0
```

I need:

```
var 1-column    var 2 string
0,333333333        0
0                  0
0,333333333     0,333333333
0               0,333333333
0,333333333     0,333333333
0                   0
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work

```
aggregate /outfile=* mode=addvariables
 /var1_sum=sum(var1)
 /var2_sum=sum(var2).
compute var1 = var1/var1_sum.
compute var2 = var2/var2_sum.
list var1 var2.
```

That should give you the variables as proportions.

Comment: This should work, but remove the period at the end of the second line (should be ` /var1_sum=sum(var1)` without period mark).